# Selenium find by id timeout exception

Tags: python, selenium, xpath, webdriver

I have a problem with Selenium. 
I have something like that DOM structure:

```
<div class="window__popup" style="display: block; transform: translateY(0px);">
    ...
    <div id="user_product_name" class="input__block">
        ...
        <input type="text" name="name" required="required" class="input">
        <div class="placeholder">Представьтесь, пожалуйста</div>
        ...
    </div>
    ...
</div>
```

So, this div isn't displayed by default, but when I click the button it becomes open. And  I have this code to locate a div which contains an id:

```
self.form_elements["UserName"] = Input(self._driver, Locator("xpath", "div[@id='user_product_name']"))
```

or

```
self.form_elements["UserName"] = Input(self._driver, Locator("id", "user_product_name"))
```

Both of these options don't work but throws a timeout exception:

```
selenium.common.exceptions.TimeoutException: Message:
```

However, this code works okay:

```
self.form_elements["UserName"] = Input(self._driver, \
        Locator("xpath", "//div[contains(@class, 'window__popup')]//div[contains(@class, 'placeholder') and text()='Представьтесь, пожалуйста']/ancestor::div[contains(@class, 'input__block')]"))
```

This is why I believe that the problem is about the div with id which is inside a hidden element. How can I solve it without writing a huge xpath?

Edit:
This code finds an element, but when I try to input, it throws an exception. Sorry, for editing.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Your working and not working locators slightly different.
In working locator you're looking for element inside div with class `window__popup`. As I could understand `div[@id='user_product_name']` not unique element and may exist in different DOM part that not visible.
Check how many elements with `user_product_name` id do you have in the DOM. Don't forget `driver.find_elemet...` return you first element located in the DOM and not visible one.

Try with css selector below:

```
.window__popup #user_product_name
```

Comment: Driver.findelement returns the first element that could be invisible as well. If you use firefox legacy driver, then it will returns the visible one if you try to locate link.